# how to compare selectedIndex to a string in listBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to create a if statement that recognizes which string has been removed from a specific list box. I thought i could do an if statement similar to the one below and get it to work but it tells me it has invalid arguements - if anyone can guide me it would appreciated

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        listBox2.Items.RemoveAt(listBox2.SelectedIndex); 
        if(listBox2.Items.RemoveAt(listBox2.SelectedItems.ToString().Equals("Test")))
        {
         picturebox.Image = null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check the `SelectedItem` *before* removing it:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listBox2.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        if (listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString().Equals("Test")))
            picturebox.Image = null;

        listBox2.Items.RemoveAt(listBox2.SelectedIndex); 
    }
}
```

I’ve also added a check to ensure that an item is actually selected (since you would get errors otherwise).

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you are calling [ListBox.Items.RemoveAt(int index)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.removeat.aspx) and passing in a boolean value: `listBox2.SelectedItems.ToString().Equals("Test"))`.

In addition, you're removing the item first, and then calling `RemoveAt` again, which will actually remove a different item (whatever is now at that index), or throw an exception if you've gone outside of the bounds of your ListBox collection.

You should first check if your selected item equals "Test", and then remove the item from your `ListBox`, like so:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // SelectedIndex returns -1 if nothing is selected
    if(listBox2.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        if( listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString().Equals("Test") )
        {
            picturebox.Image = null;
        }
        listBox2.Items.RemoveAt(listBox2.SelectedIndex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like :

```
    String deletedString = listBox2.Items.ElementAt(listBox2.SelectedIndex).ToString();
    listBox2.Items.RemoveAt(listBox2.SelectedIndex); 
    if(listBox2.Items.RemoveAt(deletedString == "Test"))
    {
     picturebox.Image = null;
    }
```

It might not compile (Check if Items has SelectedItem property).